# Why is this null termination in c++ char array not recognized

Tags: c++

I have a very simple C++ code like so:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int count_occurrences(char *pc, char c) {
    int count = 0;
    while (pc != '\0') {
        if (*pc == c) {
            ++count;
        }
        ++pc;
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    char v[6] {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}; 
    cout << "Total occurence of  'a'" << count_occurrences(&v[0], 'l');
}
```

The char array is `null` terminated, however the `while (pc != '\0')` is not able to detect the null placed at the end of the character array. I have tried `while (pc != NULL)` and `while (pc != nullptr)` but no luck.

Comment: `while(*pc != '\0')`

Comment: if warnings switched on, it should have at minimum one!

Comment: Try this ```while (*pc)```

Comment: I have compiled with `g++ -Wall -std=c++11 hello.cpp` using g++ 5.4 on Ubuntu 16 and I did not get any warnings.

Comment: I think you're confusing the null character (`'\0'`) with the null pointer. A pointer to the null character is not the same thing as a null pointer.

Comment: @sshekhar1980 You should consider upgrading your compiler. GCC 5 was released 6 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to check this out [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/)

```
while(*pc != '\0')
```